# Writing to a table which has indexes and views that are based on it

Tags: t-sql, indexing, view

The task is to load data into a semi large table (call it "SLT"). It is approx 150 mill rows and the batch size is typically around 50k rows (sql server 2016).

SLT is clustered coumnstore and has a few non-clustered indexes.

There are also a few views in the database, which are based mostly on data from this table.

Because of this (the indexes, views or both perhaps) writing to SLT is quite slow.

Normally, I would solve this by deleting the indexes, then write to SLT and recreate the indexes afterwards. However, since there are also views based on SLT, which in turn rely on the indexes to function efficiently that might be a problem.

So, obvioulsy I could to drop and recreate the views as well. However, this might break other things using the views.

So, does anyone know if there is a simpler approach.. a way to suspend all dependant items while writing to SLT?